# Java Subclass property bound or not?

Tags: java, swing, properties

I have a question regarding the use of bound properties when using Swing components. 
So, I have this very simple Java class extending the JButton class:

```
public class MyBean extends JButton
{
    public static final String PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY = "sampleProperty";
    private String sampleProperty;

    public MyBean() {

        addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                componentPropertyChange(evt);
            }
         });
     }

    public String getSampleProperty() {
        return sampleProperty;
    }

    public void setSampleProperty(String value) {
        String oldValue = sampleProperty;
        sampleProperty = value;
        firePropertyChange(PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY, oldValue, sampleProperty);
    }

    // Handle a property being updated
    static private void componentPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

        String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
        System.out.println(MyBean.class.getSimpleName() + " - '" + propertyName + "' changed");    
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        Class<?> clazz = MyBean.class;
        BeanInfo bi = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
        PropertyDescriptor[] pds = bi.getPropertyDescriptors();

        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s - %s", clazz.getSimpleName(), pd.getName(), Boolean.toString(pd.isBound())));
        }

        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setText("My name");
        myBean.setLocation(new Point(10,10));
        myBean.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (IntrospectionException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Running this application will output:

```
MyBean - UI - true
MyBean - UIClassID - true
MyBean - accessibleContext - true
MyBean - action - true
...
MyBean - vetoableChangeListeners - true
MyBean - visible - true
MyBean - visibleRect - true
MyBean - width - true
MyBean - x - true
MyBean - y - true
**MyBean - 'text' changed**
```

My question:

For all MyBean properties a line is printed telling me the property is bound, however, when I create a MyBean instance and call setText, setLocation and setVisible only in case of setText a line is printed. My conclusion is (maybe wrong) that in case setLocation and setVisible are called the **firePropertyChange** method is not called and therefore the **PropertyChangedListener** is not called. Now, I thought that the **firePropertyChange** method is called for every bound property when it gets updated? Apparently this is not the case or maybe the printed list is wrong. Any explanation on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the record (years later), there are no "visible" nor "location" bound properties, thus no event being fired.  Swing uses getFoo() and setFoo() for most bound properties, but not all of them, and there are set/get calls which in turn are not properties.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen it documented (or spotted in the source) that all set* methods cause a PropertyChangeEvent, let me know if you have and where.  In general if you want to catch calls to a method you'll need to override it.  If you do that don't forget to call the supertype's version from within the overridden method, using the 'super' keyword.

You could call firePropertyChanged from within said overridden method.

Outside of Swing code you might provide a wrapper implementation but that doesn't work with Swing as it uses concrete types instead of interfaces.

Comment: See also [*Bound Properties*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html#bound).